# Условие для проверки номера телефона

Tags: java

Добрый день, пытаюсь импортнуть в базу телефонные номера, но столкнулся с такой проблемой что некоторые телефоны начинаются с 89xx а нужно чтобы было без 8-ки, т.е. 9xx. Если первая цифра начинается с 8 а вторая 9 тогда необходимо убрать 8-ку, чтобы было все формализованно

Comment: И что вам мешает это сделать?

Comment: `if(number.startsWith("89")) number = number.substring(1);`

Comment: public void setNomerAbonenta(String nomerAbonenta) {
        if (nomerAbonenta.hashCode() == 0) {
            this.nomerAbonenta = null;
        } else {
            // TODO Если первая 8, то убрать

           // nomerAbonenta = nomerAbonenta.replaceFirst("^8", "");

            if(nomerAbonenta.startsWith("89")) nomerAbonenta = nomerAbonenta.substring(1);

         this.nomerAbonenta = nomerAbonenta;
        }
    }

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '10.11.2016 14:06:42' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: спасибо все получилось

Comment: if (nomerAbonenta.startsWith("89") && nomerAbonenta.length() == 11) {
                nomerAbonenta = nomerAbonenta.substring(1);

Answer (score 2):

Нормальный вопрос - зря минусуете :)

Это довольно распространенная проблема, проблема конвертации локальных номеров в международный стандарт. Кроме российской `8` почти в каждой стране существуют свои навороты, по сравнению с которыми, `8` это просто детские забавы.

Для решения этой проблемы есть мультиязычная (Java/C++/JS) библиотека написанная не кем-нибудь а Гуглом - называется [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber)

Либа умеет парсить номер телефона почти во всех мыслимых и немыслимых форматах и переводить в международный стандарт и наоборот.

Пользуйтесь на здоровье.

P.S. Либа является частью стандартной поставки Android (а как вы думали Android телефон распознает, что `8-9XX` - эквивалентен `+7-9XX`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (nomerAbonenta.startsWith("89") && nomerAbonenta.length() == 11) {
            nomerAbonenta = nomerAbonenta.substring(1);
```